# How do I fix error: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC284DDDFF (ucrtbased.dll) in EncodeTextApp.exe: 0xC0000005

Tags: c

I wrote this code yesterday. It compiles/builds fine with no errors and opens windows command prompt requesting me to input an original text. I input the original text that I want my program to encode and hit enter. This results in the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC284DDDFF (ucrtbased.dll) in EncodeTextApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00007FF7CAEC9C23.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

This exception above happens when I input the *message* that I want to encode in the command prompt when the program is running. Then it just crashes.

The code below is the one from my application. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_LEN 80
#define encodingshift 17

char* encode(char* str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        str[i] = str[i] - encodingshift;
        /*str[i] = (char)((int)str[i] + encodingshift) % 26;*/
    }
return (str);
}

void main() {
    char *str = "";

    printf("Please enter the message to encode: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    char* original = str;

    str = encode(str);
    printf("\nOriginal Message: %s", original);
    printf("\nEncoding Shift: %d", encodingshift);
    printf("\nEncoded message: %s", str);
    getchar();
}
```

I have done everything, from uninstalling the c++ items from Visual Studio and reinstalling them, to installing the whole of Visual Studio again but the error doesn't go away. Therefore, I would like to know what I have to do. It's the only thing stopping me from having my programs work.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The thing is that I've already looked through the debugger.

Comment: So exactly *when* does it throw the exception?

Comment: When I try to input the message I want to encode in the command prompt when the program is running @MartinBonner

Comment: You should [edit] that information in to your question, and you should remove the `encode` function (and the calls to it, and the printing of its output) from your example - because they obviously aren't relevant.

Comment: You should also accept the answer below, because it is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *str = "";

printf("Please enter the message to encode: ");
fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);
```

is wrong, `str` is a string literal (tipically placed on read only segments, thus, not modifiable) and you need room to store the string with `fgets`, change to:

```
char str[MAX_LEN];
```

and

```
str = encode(str); /* str now is an array, you can not assign to */
```

to

```
encode(str);
```

And note that you are not incrementing `i` in the `while` loop (infinite loop)

Also, you are mixing C and C++, don't do that, if you want C, `iostream` should be `stdio.h` and use a valid signature for `main`: `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`

Comment: You might want to delete the last para as the OP has now made this a strictly C question.

Comment: @MartinBonner, That's what I say: `iostream` is not a C header :)

Comment: I just don't get if i have to replace all of this 
```char *str = "";
printf("Please enter the message to encode: ");
fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin);```

 with the following:
`char str[MAX_LEN];` or just the first line.

Comment: Yes, change `str * = "";` to `char str[MAX_LEN];`, and `str = encode(str)` to `enocde(str)` thats all.

Comment: @lobfil your last question shows an appalling lack of knowledge about C and programming in general. Do you _actually_ know what you are doing?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've just started learning C at uni last week and I'm trying to do an additional exercise that was not given during the practical. That's why it comes across like that. Anyways, I still get the same Exception error, even though I changed varies things which have been suggested here.

Comment: As suggested by @MichaelWalz, dont code by try-and-error, even if you are a newbie in C, try to understand what you are doing, your code fixed: https://ideone.com/bH96gh , of course your `original` string is replaced with the encoding function, this is left as an excercise for you ;)

Comment: @lobfil sorry, my comment wasn't clear, I wasn't talking about the original _question_ which is OK, but about the _comment_ where you asked if you should replace all of this..., or just `char *str = "";`.

Comment: The comment that told me to replace `char *str = "";` with the other part was unclear to me when I read it. Thats the reason why I asked, just to be sure. @MichaelWalz

Comment: @lobfil Michael Waltz meant to say: *How do you think the line `char str[MAX_LEN];` is going to also somehow telepathically know to print `Please enter the message to encode: `, instead of `Could you type in the piece of text to mangle`, and also read the line of input.* - meaning that it should be very obvious even if one doesn't know C that these 2 lines cannot possibly be replaced by this one line.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this could not have been written better.